# password field only display only after user name entered?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formio

I am using the package below to generate a form dynamically:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-formio

I have generated a simple `login-form` using this link
https://codesandbox.io/s/cra-react-formio-iy8lz

After building, it creates a JSON.
Then, I generate a form using that JSON.

It creates the same form as expected , but *I want password field only display when user enter his/her* **userid/firstname/firstfield**

https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-smoke-07qyi

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Form
    src={{
      _id: "5b8c14217f43cc293958e2bc",
      type: "form",
      tags: [],
      owner: "553dbfc08d22d5cb1a7024f2",
      components: [
        {
          label: "First Name",
          placeholder: "Enter First Name",
          key: "firstName",
          type: "textfield",
          input: true
        },
        {
          label: "Password",
          placeholder: "Enter password",
          tableView: false,
          key: "password",
          type: "password",
          input: true,
          protected: true
        },
        {
          type: "button",
          label: "Submit",
          key: "submit",
          disableOnInvalid: true,
          input: true
        }
      ]
    }}
    onSubmit={i => {
      console.log(i);
    }}
  />,

  // <Form src="https://peb3z.sse.codesandbox.io/abc" onSubmit={(i)=>{console.log(i)}} />,
  rootElement
);
```

see update
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use json conditions:

https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-sinoussi-jswhr

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Form } from "react-formio";
import "./styles.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <Form
    src={{
      _id: "5b8c14217f43cc293958e2bc",
      type: "form",
      tags: [],
      owner: "553dbfc08d22d5cb1a7024f2",
      components: [
        {
          label: "First Name",
          placeholder: "Enter First Name",
          key: "firstName",
          type: "textfield",
          input: true
        },
        {
          label: "Last Name",
          placeholder: "Enter Last Name",
          key: "lastName",
          type: "textfield",
          input: true
        },
        {
          label: "Password",
          placeholder: "Enter password",
          tableView: false,
          key: "password",
          type: "password",
          input: true,
          protected: true,
          conditional: {
            json: {
              and: [
                {
                  "!=": [
                    {
                      var: "data.firstName"
                    },
                    ""
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "!=": [
                    {
                      var: "data.lastName"
                    },
                    ""
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          type: "button",
          label: "Submit",
          key: "submit",
          disableOnInvalid: true,
          input: true
        }
      ]
    }}
    onSubmit={i => {
      console.log(i);
    }}
  />,

  // <Form src="https://peb3z.sse.codesandbox.io/abc" onSubmit={(i)=>{console.log(i)}} />,
  rootElement
);
```

Comment: thanks for answering ...!! that is what I am looking for .1 more help .on button click I want to `hit my server` example a post request .can I do that ??

Comment: I want to hit a `post request` example `http://abc.***/senddata` with all parameter like `firstname and password`

Comment: `see my update` ..I just click button it give me `submission successfully` .i don't even  hit service

Comment: i updated the example: look at submut alert when you click: https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-sinoussi-jswhr

Comment: added  validate: {
            required: true
          } if you need disable button

Comment: I never declare `Submission Complete` alert  will display after the button click

Comment: can we hide this alert `Submission Complete` on button click

Comment: @user944513 You can use json conditionals or custom js code as well. If you want to disable alerts pass `options={{noAlerts: true}}/>` on your form component